# Spring Cloud Stream 3.x - replay message strategy

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-cloud-stream

I am looking for some guidance around replay message strategy from a Kafka topic utilizing Spring Cloud Stream 3.x / Kafka binder implementations -

1. Replay specific messages [ *for ex. by timestamp window* ] from a topic. How to reset offsets for all or some consumers within a consumer group?
2. Is it possible to replay from a specific partition of the topic [ if we know partitions for messages we are interested in replaying ]?

In general, what are the best practices around message replay. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Add a rebalance listener bean and it will be wired into the binder...

```java
@Bean
KafkaBindingRebalanceListener rebal() {
    return new KafkaBindingRebalanceListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPartitionsAssigned(String bindingName, Consumer<?, ?> consumer,
                Collection<TopicPartition> partitions, boolean initial) {

            consumer.seekToBeginning(partitions);
        }

    };
}
```

You can use any consumer seek operation; you can also call `consumer.offsetsForTimes(...)` etc.

The `initial` flag is true for the first rebalance, false, for others.

Comment: This will require a restart correct? Is there a way to force a given listener to get rebalanced (for example I would like to make a REST call - POST /api/kafka/reset and give partiton id and new offset)

Comment: You don't have to restart the whole app. If you have (or add) the Boot actuator starter to the class path, you can stop and restart the binding using `BindingsEndpoint.changeState()`.